# init.d script doesn't give standard output

Tags: logs, systemd, init.d

I'm using Debian Jessie and when I'm trying to use some script from init.d (start, stop, restart). There are functions `log_failure_msg` `log_daemon_msg` `log_end_msg` which should give something on standard output, but it doesn't. In older version of Debian I remember it works normally. Even if trying to use failed script, it always get the same output:

> kuban@lenovo-y510p:/etc/init.d$ sudo /etc/init.d/parstart restart
>
> [ ok ] Restarting parstart (via systemctl): parstart.service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to use some script from `init.d` […]

## Don't run scripts in `/etc/init.d/` directly.

On systemd operating systems there's no guarantee that those scripts even exist, let alone that they are what are specifying your service. Even on Debian 7, there were systemd units supplanting System 5 `rc` scripts; and this is more so on Debian 8. The correct commands to use are:

- `systemctl` with its `status`, `start`, `stop`, `enable`, and `disable` subcommands
- `service`
- `update-rc.d` and `invoke-rc.d`, but only if you are a package maintainer script

This is exactly what's happening to you.  Your direct invocation of the script is being replaced, via a hook inside a widely used Debian library of scripting functions, with an invocation of (in this particular case)

```
systemctl restart parstart.service
```

You can even see this in the output in front of you.  It's what the `(via systemctl): parstart.service` means.  And clearly, far from failing it is *succeeding* in telling systemd to restart the service.

The interactive bells and whistles inside your `rc` script, including coloured messages, are no longer effective.  Your service is not run as a child process of `systemctl`.  It is run as a child process of `systemd` and has zero connection with the terminal at which you are interactively running commands.

All of that `/etc/szarp/parstart.cfg` scaffolding and log message generation is entirely unnecessary with systemd, anyway.  systemd provides cross-service mechanisms for enabling and disabling services, and for auto-restarting them.  It logs when it starts and stops services, without need for the services to do that.  By my count, that `rc` script is quite simply replaceable by 16 ordinary `.service` units, one for each service.  Here's what one would look like:

```
[Unit]
Description=The SZARP pserver-lite server
After=network.target 

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pserver-lite --no-daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Call that `/usr/local/etc/systemd/system/pserver-lite.service`, run `systemctl daemon-reload`, and …

- … there's status information available with `systemctl status pserver-lite.service`.
- … you enable it for running at bootstrap with `systemctl enable pserver-lite.service`.
- … you can see systemd's log entries for starting and stopping it with `journalctl`.

It's pretty much that easy for the other 15.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233840/5132
- Stephen Wadeley (2014).  ["8. Managing Services with systemd"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html) *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 System Administrators' Guide*.  Red Hat.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemctl`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.

Comment: so there is no way to get something out on terminal during restarting, just checking status after it?